# What is the best way to detect tabulated data structures?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I have a project where I have a picture (.bmp, .jpeg, etc) containing a well-defined table structure (say 4x6 or 1x10, simple structure). I need to extract data from cells from that picture, all I need is to detect where a cell starts and ends (pixel coordinates, or anything else if there are other ways), so I can work with the portion of image inside that cell. I've gained some experiences with some artificial intelligence projects (TD-learning, Q-learning, Neural Networks) but never worked on a project that required computer vision, so my knowledge in that field is quite limited. Any indication, or algorithm that comes to mind, for detecting the table structure on the picture?

Comment: A table may be styled in many different ways (with or without outer borders, cell borders). There's also the alignment issue: your table might not be exactly lined up with your image borders. I would rather try to detect the numbers in the cells, and their alignment on both axes, I imagine that this is how we detect these patterns.

Comment: However, my suggestion is based on some kind of preexisting OCR work being done on the image, upon which the detection would take place. Maybe you are thinking of a different approach.

Comment: See http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=577043

Comment: And http://www.dfki.uni-kl.de/~kieni/publications/spie98.pdf

Comment: @didierc Thank you very much for your suggestion. So your solution is to get all the character, transform it into simple text-tabulated data and apply the structure recognition based on block segmentation algorithm? I admit, that's a very good idea, and I might consider it if I can't find a way to get the structure first. I already have and well-studied an OCR algorithm (which I planned to apply once I get the cell's image).

Comment: I think the second paper is closer to what I had in mind. That's how I would try to do it, assuming the OCR provides all the necessary information. In retrospect, I suppose you had already made some research on the topic and found those papers earlier, so perhaps you are looking for other options: this approach looks more like an analytical one than a machine learning one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) for identifying the cells' boundaries.

Then (depending on the content of the cells) use an [OCR tool](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) for extracting the actual cell information.

Comment: This is amazing, judging by the description. Thank you, I'll look through it and I hope it will (should) solve my problem.